# need to search files in windows with latest time stamps through powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

i have project assigned to me, first i need to find file in which directory it is in server, code i have written

```
    $drive = get-psdrive |select root |select-string -pattern ':'
 Write-Host $drive

     foreach ($a in $drive)
        {
            Get-ChildItem $a -recurse -filter  "*DBaEnvProd*" |select  directory        
        }
there shd be one output a there will be only one dbenvprod on server
how to get one value
```

output iam getting

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with name '@{Root=C' does not exist.
At D:\temp.ps1:6 char:26
+             Get-ChildItem  <<<< $a -recurse -filter  "*DBaEnvProd*" |select  directory
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with name '@{Root=D' does not exist.
At D:\temp.ps1:6 char:26
+             Get-ChildItem  <<<< $a -recurse -filter  "*DBaEnvProd*" |select  directory
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with name '@{Root=E' does not exist.
At D:\temp.ps1:6 char:26
+             Get-ChildItem  <<<< $a -recurse -filter  "*DBaEnvProd*" |select  directory
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with name '@{Root=F' does not exist.
At D:\temp.ps1:6 char:26
+             Get-ChildItem  <<<< $a -recurse -filter  "*DBaEnvProd*" |select  directory
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with name '@{Root=Z' does not exist.
At D:\temp.ps1:6 char:26
+             Get-ChildItem  <<<< $a -recurse -filter  "*DBaEnvProd*" |select  directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-InputObject` parameter:

```
Select-String -InputObject {$_.Root} -Pattern ':'
```

Comment: iam getting output but i am getting errors as well Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tanium\Tanium Client' is denied.
At D:\temp.ps1:6 char:26
+             Get-ChildItem  <<<< $a -recurse -filter  "*DBaEnvProd*" |select  directory
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup' is denied.
At D:\temp.ps1:6 char:26
+             Get-ChildItem  <<<< $a -recurse -filter  "*DBaEnvProd*" |select  directory

Directory
---------
E:\Utility\batfiles

Comment: That's because `Get-PSDrive` returns more than just the local drives and mapped network drives.

Comment: iam using in a tool its showing one line and then this error     <line index="1">Copyright 2010 BMC Software Ltd, Version: 1.6.2  </line>
            <line index="2">Connecting to remote service...</line>
            <line index="3">Connected to remote host.</line>
            <line index="4">A:\ C:\ D:\ E:\ F:\ G:\ I:\ J:\ K:\ Z:\</line>
            <line index="5">The pipe is being closed.</line>
            <line index="6">Error while reading hRemoteStdErrorPipe: ListenRemoteStdOutputPipeThread()</line>

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-PSDrive | ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.Root -Filter "*DBaEnvProd*" -Recurse}
```

Comment: While this code-only post might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so.